# Cordova/phonegap: FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR with file transfer plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer, phonegap

In my phonegap app I take a picture with my camera and it works as expected.

Then, I'd like to send it to my server. I see that sending the base64 encoded string is a bad practice and I figured the best solution is using the file transfer plugin.

So, I added the plugin and I wrote this:

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    try{
        var url = "myserver/addPhoto";
        alert(url);
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.fileKey = "recFile";
        var imagefilename = imageURI;
        options.fileName = imagefilename;
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.params = { "token": APP.TOKEN};
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        alert(imagefilename);
        ft.upload(imageURI, url, win, fail, options); 
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}
```

In the last line in the try branch, I get the error **FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR**.

In the alert before this line, I show in the alert the path (*imagefilename* variable). If I try to go manually in that path in my Android device, I can't find it. The path is *file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.My.App/cache/1505307795417.jpg*

So, I tried to set the option

```
saveToPhotoAlbum: true
```

to check if the image is saved and I correctly see the photo in my album. I don't know why I get the error while sending it, can be the path wrong?

I don't think the problem is server side, since I can't even see the request in the server log.

**UPDATE**:

I also tried this after Anuj T suggestion, but the result is still the same:

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var filepath;
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function success(fileEntry) {

        // Do something with the FileEntry object, like write to it, upload it, etc.
        // writeFile(fileEntry, imageURI);
        filepath = fileEntry.fullPath;
        alert("got file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
        // displayFileData(fileEntry.nativeURL, "Native URL");

        try {
            var url = "myUrl";
            alert(url);
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            options.fileKey = "recFile";
            var imagefilename = filepath;
            options.fileName = imagefilename;
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.params = { "token": APP.TOKEN }; // if we need to send parameters to the server request
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            alert(imagefilename);
            alert(imageURI);

            ft.upload(filepath, url, win, fail, options);
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.message);
        }

    }, function () {
        // If don't get the FileEntry (which may happen when testing
        // on some emulators), copy to a new FileEntry.
        alert("file system fail");
        createNewFileEntry(imgUri);

    });


}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is my server side code.

```
internal GenericResponse AddChiusuraPhoto(string token)
    {
        Utility.Logger("AddChiusuraPhoto");
        var gr = new GenericResponse();
        if (CheckToken(token, out IS_UTENZE utente))
        {
            try
            {
                var md5 = new md5Manager();
                HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["recFile"];
                if (file == null)
                    return null;
                string targetFilePath = @"C:\ProgramData\" + file.FileName;
                file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
                Utility.Logger("[AddChiusuraPhoto] Returning lista ");
                return gr;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                gr.ESITO = "[KO]";
                gr.MESSAGGIO = ex.ToSafeString();
                Utility.Logger("AddChiusuraPhoto " + gr.MESSAGGIO);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gr.ESITO = "[KO]";
            gr.MESSAGGIO = "Utente non loggato, impossibile effettuare il logout.";
            Utility.Logger("AddChiusuraPhoto " + gr.MESSAGGIO);
        }
        return gr;
    }
```

Note that this is a WCF. This is the addressing part:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "chiusure/addPhoto", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
GenericResponse AddChiusuraPhoto(string token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to take a picture and get a FileEntry Object**

If you need to use a FileEntry object, set the destinationType to **Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI** in your CameraOptions object

**UPDATED CODE**

```
function getPicture(){

      var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
      var options = setOptions(srcType);
      //var func = createNewFileEntry;

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {

          //displayImage(imageUri);
          // You may choose to copy the picture, save it somewhere, or upload.
          //func(imageUri);
          var filename = imageUri.substr(imageUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function success(dirEntry) {

              // Do something with the FileEntry object, like write to it, upload it, etc.
              // writeFile(fileEntry, imgUri);
              console.log("got file: " + dirEntry.fullPath);

              console.log("file name " + filename);
              // JPEG file
              dirEntry.getFile(filename, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

                      // Do something with it, like write to it, upload it, etc.
                      // writeFile(fileEntry, imgUri);
                      console.log("got file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);
                      // displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath, "File copied to");
                      upload(fileEntry);

                  }, onErrorCreateFile);                      
              // displayFileData(fileEntry.nativeURL, "Native URL");
          }, function () {
            // If don't get the FileEntry (which may happen when testing
            // on some emulators), copy to a new FileEntry.
              //createNewFileEntry(imgUri);
          });
          //console.log(imageUri);

      }, function cameraError(error) {
          console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

      }, options);
 };
```

set option function.

```
function setOptions(srcType) {
  var options = {
      // Some common settings are 20, 50, and 100
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI ,
      // In this app, dynamically set the picture source, Camera or photo gallery
      sourceType: srcType,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      allowEdit: false,
      saveToPhotoAlbum:false,
      correctOrientation: true  //Corrects Android orientation quirks
  };
  return options;
}
```

See the detail explanation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#take-a-picture-and-get-a-fileentry-object-).

**To Upload the file to the server**

```
function upload(fileEntry) {

 var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

 var success = function (r) {
     console.log("Successful upload..." + JSON.stringify(r));
     console.log("Code = " + JSON.stringify(r.responseCode));
     alert(JSON.stringify(r.response));
     // displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + " (content uploaded to server)");
 };

 var fail = function (error) {
     alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
     console.log("Error= " + error);
 };

 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey = "file";
  options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";

 options.params = params;

 var SERVER = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";

 var ft = new FileTransfer();
 // SERVER must be a URL that can handle the request, like
 // http://some.server.com/upload.php
 ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(SERVER), success, fail, options);
}
```

when you get the success alert you can also check your params uploaded to the server or not, you will receive the link in success.

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, how am I supposed to use fileEntry.fullPath?It has to be set as value of options.fileName?

Comment: Look my update. I changed a little your code, since the ft.upload was executed before the resolveLocalFileSystemURL. The result is still file not found... do you know why?

Comment: can your try static fileurl path..?? coz i am not able recreate the issue on my side.. just try "var fileURL = "///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/yourpic.jpg"
see if that works...make sure yourpic.jpg exist in your file system.

Comment: Hi Anuj, there isn't "fileUrl" in your sample code... maybe do you mean "filepath = fileEntry.fullPath;" and change to "filepath = "///etc/etc"?

Comment: ya filepath in the code "var filepath = "///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/yourpic.jpg".

Comment: I tried with "filepath = "///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20170919_165612.jpg";". I took the path from my gallery, in the image details. I don't know why is quite different from your path sample... anyway, I get still the same error...this error type, imho, is client side, but I don't know what I can try, so I ask you... can be a server side problem?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: did your issue solve ?? actually i am not able to recreate the issue.i just check the file-transfer plugin i am having is version 1.6.2

Comment: updated my answer, check edit 2, its demo i have which is working correctly..just call the uploadFile() function on button click and check.

Comment: Thanks for the code Anuj and excuse me for my delay. I tried to executed this code with a try catch statement when call the uploadFile. I created a simple alert with the catch message and it isn't never displayed. But, I don't see anything also on my server side... can you see my update? I inserted my server side code.. or maybe do you have a server side sample for this scope?

Comment: Just check with same server uri as in my example.. If upload works it will give u success code.. 200 and response. That uri works. Try that function as it is..just call it as it is..no change..

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't get it! It seems it worked, since I see the alert (I replaced the console.log with alert) with 200 code. Can I do the same with a WCF web service?

Comment: ya any web service will work.. just make sure you send the the response from ws..to check if req hit your webservice..just send response..

Comment: updated  and finalize the answer..with the code to get the picture from camera also. :)

Comment: Using my address I get the error "An error has occurred: Code = 1".... what's wrong on my server side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155407/discussion-between-anuj-t-and-piero-alberto).